# Cost of an Umbrella Policy

Tags: united-states, insurance, car-insurance, home-insurance

About me, I am single and  I own a car. I also own a home. I live in New Jersey.

I recently got a quote on  a 5 million dollar umbrella policy and a quote on a 10 million dollar umbrella policy for my self. I would expect the second policy to cost more but not twice the amount of the first policy. The cost of the second policy was more than double the  cost of the first  policy. Why would that be?

Comment: Smaller pool of insured? You're rich enough to afford it? Who knows...

Comment: What does your insurance broker say when you ask them? Have you tried getting other quotes? Maybe they're just afraid that anyone insured for that much will be tempted to commit insurance fraud

Comment: Umbrella policies cover risk beyond what auto/home covers. E.g., if you have a 300k auto limit and 5m umbrella, the umbrella policy covers auto risks between 300k and 5m, or a potential loss to the insurer of 4.7m. A 10m policy has a potential loss of 9.7m, more than double the 5m policy. Also, perhaps the insurer simply doesn't want to write this much risk so they price higher to disincentivize sales.

Comment: @keshlam I asked my insurance broker why the pricing was they way it was and he said he did not know, I have not gotten any other quotes but  I plan to.

Comment: If he doesn't know, I doubt we can do more than guess.

Comment: My insurance company states they will contest any claims made against my umbrella policy. So they likely factor in increased legal costs for a larger liability suit.

Comment: 10M is unusually large for a private umbrella insurance and hence it's not as common as 3M or 5M one. Typically people insure up to their net worth and if you happen to be a high net worth individual, you are a more attractive target for a law suit.